# Inconsistent results from Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, django-orm

Can anyone shed some light on this unusual behavior? I'm debugging a Django manager, and it seems to be the case that the ORM is changing the results it returns for the same query. Look at the following series of commands (run in the debugger during a test):

The first line is a command which should return the member associated with the most recent session tagged with a specific uuid. The two uuids at play here are `uuid1 = 1234cat` and `uuid2=9876dog`. You'll see how towards the end of this series of commands, the exact same command begins to return a different value. No data was changed, and I entered nothing except the commands you see here.

```
ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last().member
<Member: (681)  , INACTIVE>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at')
[<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>, <Session: (680)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>]

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (681)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

# RESULT CHANGES
ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (680)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last()
<Session: (680)  , INACTIVE, 9876dog>

ipdb> Session.objects.filter(uuid=uuid2).order_by('knz_updated_at').last().member
<Member: (680)  , INACTIVE>
```

What's also bizarre is that this error does not occur when running the test individually, or when running test for just the `member` app. Only when I run the test suite for the entire project does this problem occur.

We're using MySQL as the database, if that helps.

Comment: Hard to say. Can you show us some more code, such as your model and your `get_or_create_by_uuid()` method?

Comment: Ok, I recreated the issue using only Django ORM manager methods.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the issue by changing the `order_by('knz_updated_at)` clause to `order_by('knz_updated_at', 'id')`.

It seems that, in cases where both objects were updated in the same second, the ORM can be ambiguous about what value it returns (since Django `DateTimeField` only stores resolution to the second). Adding the `id` to the sort ensures that in cases of identical update times, the object created more recently will be returned.